# Update multiple records with something different for each Primary Key

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database which contains 300k records, each with 30 columns. Each day, I receive an update to *some* fields for _some_records, but the updated value is unique.

Can I overwrite every record in the update? I'm looking for a dream solution like this:

```
OVERWRITE (col2, col3, col4, col5... col30)
VALUES (PRIMARYKEY1, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value),
(PRIMARYKEY2, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value),
(PRIMARYKEY3, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value),
(PRIMARYKEY4, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value);
```

I've looked at UPDATE SET, but that seems to only let me change one column per query so I'd need 30 queries.

Comment: *I've looked at UPDATE SET, but that seems to only let me change one column per query* where did you look? In a single update statement you can update as many column as you want: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: You probably mean "only let me change one **row** per query".

Comment: Paul is right - I did. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how/where you formed the impression that an `UPDATE` statement can only update one column at a time. This is not the case. For MySQL, the `UPDATE` syntax is described in the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). There is at least one example given showing more than one column being updated in a single statement.

If you need to update certain columns in several specific rows, where the new data needs to be set to the the same value in each updated row, then as long as you know the IDs of those rows, it's fairly straightforward to do so. For example:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET 
  col2 = 'newcol2value',
  col3 = 'newcol3value',  
  col6 = 'newcol6value',  
  col30 = 'newcol30value'
WHERE
  id IN (1, 3, 7, 656)
```

If that's not what you mean, you'll need to clarify the requirements a little.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ADyson. You're right - I am completely wrong. What I meant to say is that you can only update one primary key per set. I've created a concatenated query on Excel for each row of updates, and pasted them all into MySQL which works.

Comment: Well that's not strictly true either - look at my `IN` clause :-). Glad you found a solution though

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize (exploit) the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If you specify an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause and a row to be
>   inserted would cause a duplicate value in a `UNIQUE` index or
>   `PRIMARY KEY`, an
>   [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) of the
>   old row occurs.

```
INSERT into my_table (PRIMARYKEY, col2, col3, col4, col5... col30)
VALUES
    (PRIMARYKEY1, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value),
    (PRIMARYKEY2, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value),
    (PRIMARYKEY3, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value),
    (PRIMARYKEY4, newcol2value, newcol3value, newcol4value...newcol30value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    col2 = VALUES(col2),
    col3 = VALUES(col3),
    col4 = VALUES(col4),
    col5 = VALUES(col5),
    ...
    col30 = VALUES(col30)
```

But note that if one of new datas PRIMARYKEY doesn't already exist in the table, a new row will be inserted.